# ServiceStack custom format and vendor specific content types

Tags: servicestack, hypermedia

I am trying to add a custom format for HAL (hypertext application language). I have my custom format handler created, I followed along with the ServiceStack v-card example, and all is working fine there and I was able to register it with ServiceStack.

The problem is that in my custom format I am trying to specify a content-type of "hal+json"

When I make a GET request to my service, and specify the format like so:

'http://mylocalserver:555555/items?format=hal+json'

ServiceStack defaults back to using just Json. I have tried changing the content type to something different like "halj" and ServiceStack formats requests that use "?format=halj" using my custom formatter fine.

I pulled down the source for ServiceStack and found that any request that comes in it checks the query string for a format, and if the format evens contains "json" it will default to the Json formatter.

Is there any way around this? I have been trying to find some documentation about how to override this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `+` is a special variable on a url. Try Url encoding it, e.g:

```
http://mylocalserver:555555/items?format=hal%2Bjson
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I set the content-type of my HAL json formatter to use application/hal+json and tried making a request using ?format=hal%2Bjson but it just defaults back to html. I did however figure out that I can just set the accept header to application/hal+json and that works fine. So I guess I just can't use the url method of specifying the content-type using hal+json, but thats not a ServiceStack issue, it's just a url thing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ok I'll look into making it it work better in a future version of SS with `?format=hal+json` and convert the ' ' that comes across un-encoded back into the desired `+` so it works as expected.